# Online consultation: Should notes be ready right after the consultation?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research

We are building an online consultation app where in there's a consultant and a customer who can do a video conference over the phone / desktop computer.

On the **consultant's** side, we are planning to allow them to type notes while they are talking to the **customer**. However, this note-taking may be quite a lot and there's a time limit to the conference (say, 15 mins.)

Once the 15 mins. is over, the conference would end (the **customer** will see an "Appointment has ended!" page).

Now, it would be great that once the consultation is over, the **customer** can immediately read a summary of the consultation. However, there may be instances that this is not possible, since the **consultant** may need more time to write more notes.

Is this a good way to approach this?

1. For those **consultants** who can type brief summary, then as per normal, the **customer** will receive the notes right after the conference ends. For those **consultants** who need more time, the **customer** will need to be further notified (via Push notification & email), that the notes are ready to view (which may take 5-10 minutes after the consultation).

**OR**

2. Just make it notification-based. Meaning, every time a consultation ends, the **customer** would need to be notified when their notes are ready for viewing. That is so that they would have a consistent expectation after the call ends.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely #2.

As a consultant the last thing I want to be doing is focusing on the cleanliness of my notes instead of the client.

It doesn't have to be complicated. A "Consultation notes from this meeting are being refined and will be sent to you shortly." is fine. Give a time estimate "less than 20 minutes." for a confidence booster.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the typing-up stops the clock?  It would be very bad to run out the 15 minutes of paid time waiting for the consultant to type up their notes.

Apropos afterwards, inform the customer that the consultant is still writing up the notes from the interview, and the result will be sent immediately it's ready.  Then every 5 minutes send mail saying something to the effect of "not ready yet, still working diligently, you haven't been forgotten or the report lost"